# return withSuccess withErrors lost

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using a request validation to validate my form post which works fine for a "simple" contact class but not for my posts class.

**Working:**

ContractController GET:

```
public function showForm()
    {
        return view('contact');
    }
```

ContractController POST:

```
public function sendContactInfo(ContactRequest $request)
    {
blabla
return back()
            ->withSuccess("Thank you");
}
```

**not working:**

postcontroller GET:

```
public function changepost($postid)
    {

        $postdetail = posts::find($postid);
blabla
return view('changepost')->with("postdetail", $postdetail);
}
```

postcontroller POST:

```
public function changepostvalues(changepostreqeust $request)
    {
blabla
return back()->withSuccess("Thank you");
}
```

`withSuccess` and `withError` is only stored for the next request, correct?
I've also tried to use `Session:flash` with the same result, success and error are not in the session.
when I try `Session::put` all work fine. however I don't want to store the messeage permanently in the session and I also want to understand why the infromations are lost...

I believe it has something to do with the `return view('changepost')->with("postdetail", $postdetail);` where I need to pass also the error and success messages....

Thanks.

**EDIT**
Add View

```
@extends('master')

@section('title', 'lala')

@section('sidebar')
    @parent

@endsection

@section('page-script')

        <link href="{{ asset('/packages/dropzone/dropzoneaddpost.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">


        @foreach($images as $image)
            <meta name="postimage" content="{{$image->image_path}}" id="{{$image->id}}">
        @endforeach


@stop
@section('content')
    <div align="center">
        <div class="addpost">
            @if (Session::has('success'))
                <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('success') }}</div>
            @endif


            <div class="row">
                <div class="files" id="previews">
                <div id="template" class="file-row">
                    <!-- This is used as the file preview template -->
                    <div>
                        <span class="preview"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <strong class="error text-danger" data-dz-errormessage></strong>
                    </div>
                    <div style="text-align: center;">

                        <button data-dz-remove class="btn delete mydelbutton">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">

                <form action="/changepost" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txttitle">Titel:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="txttitle" type="text" name="beschreibung" id="beschreibung" maxlength="45" style="" value='{{ $postdetail->beschreibung }}'>
                    <label for="txtmessage">Beschreibung:</label>
                    <textarea id="txtmessage" class="form-control" rows="5" name="description" id="description" maxlength="500">{{$postdetail->text}}</textarea>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="postid" value="{{ $postdetail->id }}">


                <button id="savepost" class="btn mybutton start">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Save</span>
                </button>
               </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="{{ asset('/packages/dropzone/dropzone.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('/packages/dropzone/dropzone-config.js') }}"></script>
@stop
```

Comment: Have you tried it this way `return back()->with(['success' => 'Thank you!']);`?

Comment: yes, same result... i think this is the same as Session::flash

Comment: For flash message I usually use this package https://github.com/laracasts/flash, but I'm not sure if it'll help with what you're trying to do.

Comment: i found the problem - as in laravel 5.2 the web middleware is used by default. i had a group which includes the web and auth middleware. i've remove the web part and now all works fine!

Comment: You should use the **web** middleware on all of your routes. It encrypts the cookies, protects against CSRF and other good stuff that you certainly need.

Comment: the web middleware is in 5.2 default assigned to all routes! see https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware    Keep in mind, the web middleware group is automatically applied to your default routes.php file by the RouteServiceProvider.

Comment: Ohh I see, I didn't know that. So you basically were applying the web middleware twice and that's why it wasn't working?

Comment: correct - if you include the web middleware twice it will destroy the session